# How to deploy node app on openshift and run it?

Tags: node.js, deployment, openshift

Just created a very simple hello world app using node:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});
var server_port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080
var server_ip_address = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1'

app.listen(server_port, server_ip_address, function () {
  console.log( "Listening on " + server_ip_address + ", port " + server_port )
});
```

and it works as it is expected in my local machine,

put that on github and deployed it on openshift, pod created and server running fine:
[image]
 but when I browse [the route](http://kavehnode-kaveh.193b.starter-ca-central-1.openshiftapps.com/) which I could find it in Application>>routes menu it says:

```
Application is not available

The application is currently not serving requests at this endpoint. It may not have been started or is still starting.
I guess I'm using the latest version of openshift since just created an account.
```

I'm expecting it to show me the Hello world!

update1:

here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "npmtest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application server IP address needs to be `0.0.0.0`. So you either specify an environment variable for that, or hard code it.

Comment: I replaced the ip with 0.0.0.0 but still not working

Comment: Oh actually after 1 minute it worked with the 0.0.0.0 ip !
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

have you configure main file in package.json

and maybe you need to get port dynamically from the environment variables check below link for openshift sample

https://github.com/openshift/nodejs-ex

Comment: yes i edited my post and included the package.json which has the main configured.
I believe I'm setting the IP dynamically using this line:
var server_ip_address = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1'